# where is "create instance" menu in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

in visual studio 2008 there is a sub-menu called "create instance" which is resides in class designer.
Today I've opened VS.net 2010 and then opened class designer and create my class over there and when I wanted to test my class with the help of "create instance" option there was no such option available in vs.net 2010.

and I've googled about it a little bit but no answer at all so I decided to mention about it here.

where can I find this menu in vs.net 2010?

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is my answer :
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/visual-studio-2010-rip-list-partial)
the Object Test Bench was in bye bye list of VS.net 2010.